# WebAssembly error "Protocol not available"

Tags: webassembly

I have a database driver written in Go (using [go-mssqldb](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb)) that works fine alone and I've compiled it to WebAssembly. When I run the wasm file it connects successfully and immediately query something basic like `"SELECT @@version"` this client returns the error `Protocol not available`. Is it possible to make network requests from WebAssembly? Are there special considerations when doing so? Does this error mean it is impossible to use a driver in this way? What provides this error (where does it come from...the OS or the browser?) and where are these documented (especially how can I better understand the error in this specific case and more generally when using WebAssembly)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

For better understanding on WASM, you should accept one thing: **WebAssembly in the web browser is JavaScript**. Sure, you are running Go program, however, the WASM runs in a web browser's JS engine. This implies that, in WASM, you cannot do what JS cannot. Your Go libraries are internally implemented using JS APIs only. You never be able to touch low-level OS APIs directly.

This means that you cannot connect the SQL server directly because JS cannot use low-level socket networking other than WebSockets. In server side, your SQL server must accept WebSocket in order to make it work. One way to achive it is to use [Websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify). In clients side, I have zero experience in Go programing but you should be able to get documentations regaring socket communication and WebSockets in WemAssembly.